# I tried installing brew core utilities and I got this error "Installing... Warning: No available formula with the name "coreutils""

Tags: terminal

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...

I tried installing core utilities for SHELLS by 4ndr34z

Comment: `brew search coreutils` gives me: coreutils
uutils-coreutils
xml-coreutils
moreutils
recutils
corectl
icoutils
coinutils
docutils.
Then I do `brew install coreutils` to install all of the GNU core utils like `cp`, `sed` etc.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a `brew update` first?